# How can I match between known XML tags?

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to build a list of urls contained in an xml document where I am matching everything inside of `<id>http://xxx.xxxx.com</id>` and I'm having trouble.

I'm trying to match this pattern: `/(?<id>)http://(.*?).com(?=</id>)/g`

It works on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) but I cannot seem to get it to work with my jsfunction:

```
var regEx = new RegExp('/(?&lt;id>)http://(.*?).com(?=&lt;/id>)/g');
```

I am getting an error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //(?<id>)http://(.*?).com(?=</id>)/g/: Invalid group

Comment: What did you intend `(?...)` to mean?

Comment: I'm looking to match the content within the <id> and </id> tags, which is a url in this case. It will always begin with http:// and end with .com, so this pattern will match, but it's not working for me in JS as I'm getting the error I've shown.

Comment: I understood that. But `(?...)` is invalid, so I wanted to know why you used this character sequence (`(` followed by `?`).

Comment: @FelixKling: Did you intend to write `(?:<id>)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
 (?!<id>)http:\/\/(.*?)\.com(?=<\/id>)
```

Instead of:

```
 (?<id>)http://(.*?).com(?=</id>)
```

see demo here: http://regex101.com/r/xH8mH7

Answer (score 1):

Try [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Parsing_XML) ;

```
// Code tested under Firefox 27
var doc = new DOMParser()
    .parseFromString('<id>http://xxx.xxxx.com</id>', "application/xml");
var ids = doc.querySelectorAll('id'); // Return: NodeList[id]
```

However it doesn't work in IE <= 8 ([Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Browser_compatibility))